# maximum vector in $\Bbb R^n$ which any two of them has dot product less than 0

Tags: inner-products

I'm thinking of in $\Bbb R^n$, at most how many vectors can we have any two of them's dot product are less than 0

In $\Bbb R^3$, I guess that there are at most $4$ vector but I can't prove it.(at least algebrically)

What approach can you suggest to deal with this?

Remark: In a previous edition of this question I was asking about vectors with dot product less than $1$ instead of $0$. From the answers below, there would be infinitely many of such vectors.

Comment: This question has no sense. There's not a maximum number of such vectors. Just pick any set of vectors whose norm is less than one, Cauchy Schwarz shows that this set would satisfy your condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can find $n+1$ such vectors on $\mathbb R^n$, for example by taking the vertices of an origin-centric simplex (triangle in case $n=2$, tetrahedron in case $n=3$, etc.).

We cannot find $n+2$ such vectors.
Assume otherwise, i.e., for some $n\ge 0$ we have $v_1,\ldots, v_{n+2}\in\mathbb R^n$ with $\langle v_i,v_j\rangle <0$ for $i\ne j$. 
Note that $v_{n+2}\ne0$ because $\langle v_{n+2},v_1\rangle <0$. Consider the hyperplane $V$ orthogonal to $v_{n+2}$ and project all other vectors into this hyperplane. The projected vectors are of the form $u_i=v_i+c_iv_{n+2}$ where $0=\langle u_i,v_{n+2}\rangle=\langle v_i,v_{n+2}\rangle+c_i\left|v_{n+2}\right|^2 $ implies $c_i=-\frac{\langle v_i,v_{n+2}\rangle}{\left|v_{n+2}\right|^2}>0$. Then 
$$\langle u_i,u_j\rangle
=\langle u_i,v_j\rangle +c_j\langle u_i,v_{n+2}\rangle 
=\langle u_i,v_j\rangle=\langle v_i,v_j\rangle+c_i\langle v_{n+2},v_j\rangle<0$$
so that by identifying the hyperplane $V$ with $\mathbb R^{n-1}$  we found $n+1$ vectors in $\mathbb R^{n-1}$ with pairwise negative dot product.
Together with the observation that we cannot find two vectors with negative dot product in $\mathbb R^0$, this makes a proof by induction that $n+2$ such vectors in $\mathbb R^n$ are not possible for any $n$ at all.

Comment: It is very good. Thanks a lot

Comment: Nice. This is the easiest and straightforward reasoning I have ever seen for this.

Answer (score 1):

There are infinitely many vectors in $\mathbb R^n$ such that any pairwise product will be less than one.

Take, for example, the set
$$S=\{v\in\mathbb R^n| v\cdot v = 1\}$$

So each vector in $S$ has a norm less than $1$.

Then, any $v,w\in S$ satisfy the equation $$v\cdot w \leq |v||w| = 1$$

---

For example, here are, for $n\geq 2$, sixvectors that belong to the set $S$:

$$v_1 = \left(1,0,0,\dots,0\right)\\
v_2 = \left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}},\frac{1}{\sqrt5},0,\dots,0\right)\\
v_3 = \left(\frac{\sqrt3}{\sqrt{5}},\frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt5},0,\dots,0\right)\\
v_4 = \left(\frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt{5}},\frac{\sqrt3}{\sqrt5},0,\dots,0\right)\\
v_5 = \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}},\frac{2}{\sqrt5},0,\dots,0\right)\\
v_6 = \left(0,1,0,\dots,0\right)$$

Comment: I think the equality (the part 'equals to 1' ) only holds in R^2

Comment: @YuiHongNg I **defined** the set $S$ as "the set of all vectors whose norm is equal to $1$". Why would this hold only in $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: @YuiHongNg For example, the vector $(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)$ is in the set $S$ if $n=8$.

Comment: @YuiHongNg I gave you an example of $6$ vectors in $S$. In fact, the set $S$ is infinite, as you can probably see.

Comment: I am sorry, I type my question wrongly, I want to ask for vectors dot product less than 0

Comment: @YuiHongNg Then please edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $a = (1,0,…,0), b= (-1,0,…,0)$. This gives a dot product of $-1<0$, and then we have an uncountably infinite number of such pairs with the same dot product, one for each $\lambda∈ℝ\setminus \{0\}$: $$(\lambda,0,…,0)\text{ and }\left(\frac{-1}{\lambda},0,…,0\right)$$

One can deduce there are many others, from the equality $a· b = |a| |b| \cos \angle ab$ (just choose an obtuse angle)